# Google Chart Line

Tags: asp, google-charts

Tenho projeto de uso caseiro, todo feito e ASP Clássico (VBScript) no qual utilizo informações geradas em um array à partir de arquivos txt. O projeto tem vários módulos de geração de gráficos de barra gerados "na mão" (com VBScript), e agora resolvi usar O Google Charts para gerar gráficos de linha. Consegui uma forma para gerar, dinamicamente, linhas para os gráficos

```
data.addRows
   ([

   <%FOR J = PRMDIA TO ULTDIA%>
         [<%=J%>, <%=TABVOL08(J)%>, <%=TABVOL14(J)%>, <%=TABVOL23(J)%>],
   <%NEXT%>

   ]);
```

É um gráfico único com 3 linhas distintas. Meu problema é que os valoes apresentados no gráfico aparecem diferentes do origina.
Uso assim as informações

```
view.setColumns
([0, 1, { calc: "stringify", sourceColumn: 1, type: "string", role: "annotation" },
2, { calc: "stringify", sourceColumn: 2, type: "string", role: "annotation" },
3, { calc: "stringify", sourceColumn: 3, type: "string", role: "annotation" }
```

Imagino que seja esse

Comment: Sua pergunta parece estar incompleta. "Imagino que seja esse" o que?

Comment: O problema para que os valores originais estejam sendo alterados.